# Spring transactions TransactionSynchronizationManager: isActualTransactionActive vs isSynchronizationActive

Tags: spring, transactions, synchronization

I am a little bit confused about transaction resource management in Spring. Namely, I am confused about the usage of `TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive` and `TransactionSynchronizationManager.isSynchronizationActive`.

Up to now, probably incorrectly, I assumed that `isSynchronizationActive` was used (also within the Spring codebase) to figure out whether there is an active transaction, initiated by `TransactionSynchronizationManager.initSynchronization()`. As far as I am concerned, when we suspend a transaction, the actual `isSynchronizationActive` is still true! I presume, therefore, the correct way of establishing a running transaction is by using `isActualTransactionActive`, correct?

If this is the case, what is the actual point of `isSynchronizationActive` method? I understand it tells you whether you can add synchronizations or not, but I am a bit lost about what it tells us about the transaction...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will notice the following fields of `TransactionSynchronizationManager`

```
private static final ThreadLocal<Set<TransactionSynchronization>> synchronizations =
        new NamedThreadLocal<Set<TransactionSynchronization>>("Transaction synchronizations");

private static final ThreadLocal<Boolean> actualTransactionActive =
        new NamedThreadLocal<Boolean>("Actual transaction active");
```

and the methods

```
public static boolean isSynchronizationActive() {
    return (synchronizations.get() != null);
}

public static boolean isActualTransactionActive() {
    return (actualTransactionActive.get() != null);
}
```

The `TransactionSynchronizationManager` basically acts as a registry for `TransactionSynchronization`. The javadoc states

> If transaction synchronization isn't active, there is either no
>   current transaction, or the transaction manager doesn't support
>   transaction synchronization.

So you first init and register `TransactionSynchronization` with `initSynchronization()` and `registerSynchronization(TransactionSynchronization)`. When these are registered, the `TransactionManager` can start a `Transaction` and tell the `TransactionSynchronizationManager` if it's active or not with `setActualTransactionActive(boolean)`.

In conclusion, `isSynchronizationActive()` tells us if `TransactionSynchronization`  has been enabled, even if no `TransactionSynchronization` instances have been registered.

`isActualTransactionActive()` tells us if there is an actual `Transaction` object active.

The `TransactionSynchronizationManager` javadoc states

> Central helper that manages resources and transaction synchronizations
>   per thread. To be used by resource management code **but not by typical
>   application code.**

so don't ignore it.

Comment: Thanks, I got the above. I have the following question now: When try to execute the nested transaction in NOT_SUPPORTED propagation, the global transaction gets suspended, BUT the synchronizations for the non-transactional method are active. Moreover, if I execute that non-transactional code from e.g. TransactionTemplate, then transaction template will actually call `commit` on Transaction manager, in turn executing all synchronizations. This seems a bit weird to me, as something executing non-transactionally should simply be... non-transactional

Comment: @Bober02 Can you give an example (in an edit) of your `@Transactioanl` NOT_SUPPORTED method? I have an idea but not sure.